# How to analyze temporal change in wind?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, spatio-temporal-data, weather, grib

I have daily data for several years (GRIB but also available as netCDF), I would like to investigate how the wind speed and direction has changed along the migratory route of a bird (in spring) and also in smaller areas such as in between the areas where the birds stop.

Which ArcGIS tools/extensions can I potentially use?

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS 3D Analyst Tools has a tool called Add Surface Information which will take a point, line, or polygon feature and append raster data to the attribute table.  You could repeat this process for different data and 'investigate' from there.